# Windows 10 is losing my selected Cellular APN

Tags: windows, cellular-network, lte, apn

We use in our company a Tablet PC with SIM card to be able to work mobile. Mobile Internet via SIM card works in general.

The problem is that after restarting the device, Windows loses the APN selection and resets it to "automatic". With the selection "automatic" the Internet does not work anymore, because the wrong access point name is selected.

Is it possible to save the APN permanently? Currently Windows 10 loses the selected access point after restarting. (I think its a windows bug.)
A Powershell script that sets the APN profile correctly via the console may also help.

*Windows 10 enterprise, version 1809
(Is there no Microsoft/Windows Exchange Community?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We manually added an APN configuration. Windows keeps this manual APN even after restarting.

**t-mobile APN (in germany)**

configuration details for t-mobile:

> user: t-mobile
>   password: tm
>   auth: PAP
>   APN type: default,supl